# Create a Popup window in button click -WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, popup, border

Good day to all..

Basically i have window with transaction details shown in a grid based on dates. 
On a button click should open a window where i can select multiple options such as "Current Month", "3 Months" "Year" or even the dates.
By closing the popup window the data in the main window will be filtered.

My issue is creating a window which has balloon window shape (rounded corner) and drop shadow.

Please suggest how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

To make a custom shaped window, set WindowStyle to None and AllowsTransparency to True. You'll then have to draw the window border / shadow yourself to whatever shape you require.

[Here's](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/shaped-windows-in-wpf/) an example.